# SEO effects on moving an established Blogspot blog

Tags: seo, domains, blogger

I have a blog for the last 3 years on the Blogspot platform. It recently crossed the 100,000 page views mark, and is AdSense approved for the last year. I wish to shift it to a custom domain. Is it the right time? I don't want to risk not moving now so as to establish a branding for my blog, but at the same time I'm concerned whether I will end up losing all the repute the blog has earned for itself over the years.

I don't care if the traffic sees a downward spike for a few months as long as it stands assured that I get quality organic search traffic again as my blog currently gets (>90% is organic traffic). And obviously: no spam content in blog or other malpractices that attract penalties.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the guidelines provided by Google to move your blog to a new domain, using the [Change of address tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en&ref_topic=6029673) of *Search Console* and moving it won't have any bad effects on your site's SEO.